# Private def in clojure/clojurescript

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

In Clojure and clojurescript you can have a private version of defn called defn-, but how do you do the same for def, as def- doesn't seem to be included?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You have to add the `:private true` metadata key value pair.

```
(def ^{:private true} some-var :value)
;; or
(def ^:private some-var :value)
```

The second form is just a short-hand for the first one.

Answer (score 19):

It's worth mentioning, that currently it's not possible to have a private `def` (and `defn`) in ClojureScript: https://clojurescript.org/about/differences (under "special forms")

Compilation won't fail and but the `def` will stay accessible.

Answer (score 16):

If you want a def-, here's how to implement it

```
(defmacro def- [item value]
  `(def ^{:private true} ~item ~value)
)
```

Comment: This does not actually work, see this thread for an explanation https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/O7xWh72zzuo . The proper macro is `(defmacro def- [sym init] \`(def ~(with-meta sym {:private true}) ~init))`

Comment: @ark That's better but lacks support for the docstring. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50471316/1228933) for an implementation almost identical to `defn-`.

Answer (score 10):

This google group [post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/clojure/zaWlDbOhKCM/sD_iOM_k9WcJ) has a discussion about this topic. Apparently the request has been considered. According to one of the responses, `defn-` was deemed to not be a good idea and decided not to perpetuate it with `def` and others.

Comment: my take from the linked post is that `clojure.core` is not the place for `defn-`, not that `defn-` was not good at all. +1 for the link to the post, though

Answer (score 9):

Here's how to implement `def-`:

```
(defmacro def-
  "same as def, yielding non-public def"
  [name & decls]
  (list* `def (with-meta name (assoc (meta name) :private true)) decls))
```

This code is very similar to that of `defn-`, which you can look up using `(clojure.repl/source defn-)`:

```
(defmacro defn-
  "same as defn, yielding non-public def"
  {:added "1.0"}
  [name & decls]
  (list* `defn (with-meta name (assoc (meta name) :private true)) decls))
```